# Simplifying this Objective-C code for readability

Tags: objective-c, refactoring

I wrote this following Objective-C code as part of Stanford's iTunes U course on iOS programming. Are there any ways to simplify this code? The requirement is that this method return nil if the set is empty, not an empty NSSet. It's also required to take an (id), not an NSArray, and that the method doesn't crash no matter what values are passed into it.

```
+ (NSSet *)variablesUsedInProgram:(id)program {
    NSMutableArray *stack;
    id variables;
    NSMutableSet *setOfVariables;
    if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        stack = [program mutableCopy];
        int i = stack.count;
        while (i--) {
            if ([[stack objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                if ([self isOperation:[stack objectAtIndex:i]]) {
                    [setOfVariables addObject:[stack objectAtIndex:i]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (setOfVariables.count > 0) {
        variables = setOfVariables;
    }
    return variables;
}
```

Comment: Does this even work? `setOfVariables` is never initialized.

Comment: Also, what is the point of creating a mutable copy of `program` if you never actually alter its contents (via `stack`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variables` and `setOfVariables` are never initialised. In the case where `setOfVariables` (assuming it was initialised) has a count of 0, the method will return an uninitialised value. I'm not sure why you need a mutable copy of `program` since you never modify the array. I'm not sure why you need a copy of it at all actually, and you don't actually release it either (which is OK if you are using ARC or GC, but not if you are using MRC). This is how I would refactor it, the observable behaviour shouldn't be different to your method.

```
+ (NSSet *)variablesUsedInProgram:(id)program
{
    if (![program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        return nil;

    NSMutableSet *setOfVariables = [NSMutableSet set];

    foreach (id object in program)
        if ([self isOperation:object])
            [setOfVariables addObject:object];

    if (setOfVariables.count > 0)
        return setOfVariables;
    else
        return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, this is a fairly short  way to do it:

```
+ (NSSet *)variablesUsedInProgram:(id)program {
  if (![program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    return nil;

Class stringClass = [NSString class];
NSSet *setOfVariables = 
  [program objectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger  idx, BOOL *stop){
 return ([obj isKindOfClass:stringClass] && [self isOperation:obj]);
  }];
return setOfVariables.count ? setOfVariables : nil;
}
```

Comment: I thought `NSArray` doesn't have `objectsPassingTest:`, I thought that was an `NSSet` method.

Answer (score 0):

Fast enumeration should work in this situation.

```
+ (NSSet *)variablesUsedInProgram:(id)program {
    NSMutableArray *stack;
    id variables;
    NSMutableSet *setOfVariables;
    if ([program isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        stack = [program mutableCopy];
        for (NSString *string in stack)//Fast enumerate through the array for NSString's
        {
            if ([self isOperation:string]) {
                [setOfVariables addObject:string];
            }
        }
    }
    if (setOfVariables.count > 0) {
        variables = setOfVariables;
    }
    return variables;
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't return `nil` in any case, which was one of the requirements.